# Trouble initiating webhook using shopify_python_api

Tags: django, shopify

I am using the sample application from https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app and trying to find the best place to create the webhooks. Below is the finalize method from the sample code and I'm trying to create the webhooks after the session is created.

```
def finalize(request):
    shop_url = request.REQUEST.get('shop')
    try:
        shopify_session = shopify.Session(shop_url)
        request.session['shopify'] = {
            "shop_url": shop_url,
            "access_token": shopify_session.request_token(request.REQUEST)
    }
        #create the webhooks
        shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(shopify_session)

        product_hook = shopify.Webhook()
        product_hook.topic ='products/create'
        product_hook.address = settings.SHOPIFY_APP_URL + '/notify/product/'
        product_hook.format = 'json'
        product_hook.save()

    except Exception, err:
        log.error(str(err))
        messages.error(request, "Could not log in to Shopify store.")
        return redirect(reverse('shopify_app.views.login'))

    messages.info(request, "Logged in to shopify store.")

    response = redirect(_return_address(request))
    request.session.pop('return_to', None)
    return response
```

I'm not getting anything in the log so it appears to get past the webhook creation. However, no webhook is created and then I get a Django error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /finalize/

Reverse for 'root_path' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the views.py from the example app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.conf import settings
import shopify

def _return_address(request):
    return request.session.get('return_to') or reverse('root_path')

def login(request):
    # Ask user for their ${shop}.myshopify.com address

    # If the ${shop}.myshopify.com address is already provided in the URL,
    # just skip to authenticate
    if request.REQUEST.get('shop'):
        return authenticate(request)
    return render_to_response('shopify_app/login.html', {},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def authenticate(request):
    shop = request.REQUEST.get('shop')
    if shop:
        scope = settings.SHOPIFY_API_SCOPE
        redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('shopify_app.views.finalize'))
        permission_url = shopify.Session(shop.strip()).create_permission_url(scope, redirect_uri)
        return redirect(permission_url)

    return redirect(_return_address(request))

def finalize(request):
    shop_url = request.REQUEST.get('shop')
    try:
        shopify_session = shopify.Session(shop_url)
        request.session['shopify'] = {
            "shop_url": shop_url,
            "access_token": shopify_session.request_token(request.REQUEST)
        }

    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, "Could not log in to Shopify store.")
        return redirect(reverse('shopify_app.views.login'))

    messages.info(request, "Logged in to shopify store.")

    response = redirect(_return_address(request))
    request.session.pop('return_to', None)
    return response

def logout(request):
    request.session.pop('shopify', None)
    messages.info(request, "Successfully logged out.")

    return redirect(reverse('shopify_app.views.login'))
```

Adding urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'shopify_app.views.login'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^login/', 'shopify_app.views.login'),
    url(r'^authenticate/$', 'shopify_app.views.authenticate'),
    url(r'^finalize/$', 'shopify_app.views.finalize'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'shopify_app.views.logout'),
)
```

Comment: Could you post your urls.py as well?

Comment: So, *do* you have a URL named finalize?

Comment: I found the issue -  was missing a url definition: url(r'^', include('home.urls'), name='root_path'),